# what's the easiest way to upload a solution to a vsts repo?

Tags: c#, .net, git, azure-devops

What's the easiest way to upload a solution to a new VSTS repo? I've created a new repo in VSTS and I need to upload a solution to it. When I go to the repo in VSTS there's an "Upload file(s)" button which opens a "Commit" dialog.  The top panel of the Commit dialog has a "Browse..." widget which says: "Drag and drop files here or click browse to select a file"

If I provide the path where my app exists then the dialog only lets me select top-level files but not folders. I do see a way to manually add folders via the VSTS UI. Is there a simpler way to add all the contents of my solution folder at once as opposed to manually piecing this together as described above?

Comment: Clone the empty repo to your file system, then copy all your actual code into that folder.  Then commit all the changes as your "initial commit"

Comment: The common way is commit changes inyour local git repo, and then push to remote repo (VSTS git repo). And you can also refer the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/creatingrepo?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are new to Git.  The typical process for adding files to a repo is to commit them, then push those commits to your "remote".

I am assuming that your existing code does not have git enabled right?  So the easiest thing for you to do is "Clone" the empty VSTS repo to your local machine.  Then you want to drag or copy the contents of your project into this new empty folder that your "git clone" has given you.  Once that is done you will "commit" the code (make your commit message "initial commit" or something).  Then you "push" that local commit to your remote (i.e VSTS).